# Force label to always show its full contents in Javafx

Tags: javafx

I have two controls in a `HBox`:

1. A label showing "Filter: ";
2. A text field that should be as wide as possible. That was accomplished by defining its preferred width to be as large of a number as possible (can anyone tell me why `Double.MAX_VALUE` doesn't work?)

I would have expected the `Label` to never shrink to a size smaller than what's needed to fully show its contents but I'm wrong. Is there some magical function to call that will make that for me, or will I have to keep that hardcoded `setMinWidth(40)` to get the ball rolling?

```
  val filteringPanel = new HBox() {
    val filteringLabel = new Label("Filter:") {
      setMinWidth(40) // <--- without this the label only shows "..."
    }
    val filteringTextField = new TextField() {
      setPrefWidth(100000)
    }
    setSpacing(10)
    getChildren.addAll(filteringLabel, filteringTextField)
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: You could simply use `Text`. This node doesn't grow or shrink but always keeps the size of it's text.

Comment: @fabian That worked. This should be the answer.

Comment: sizing a control is the task of the layout parent - each has a different strategy: so the solution is to use a layout and/or configure the constraints that suits your requirements best. @fabian no (and you know better ;)

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't magical function to set that up, as you already said you can use `setMinWidth`, some more controls if it might help you can be found here:  https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/size_align.htm